# How do I actually use WSGI?

Tags: python, http, wsgi

Suppose I have a function

```
def app2(environ, start_response)
```

If I know that a server implements WSGI, how can I tell the server to call app2 when it receives a HTTP request? app2 here is a function that takes a dictionary and returns a response (a WSGI application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as it sounds from your comment, your question is about Google App Engine, it provides a convenience function `run_wsgi_app` for running WSGI apps. So if your function is called `app2`, you would run

```
def main():
   run_wsgi_app(app2)
```

For more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule.html#run_wsgi_app

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the server. The WSGI-Spec says nothing about that. But mod_wsgi for example expects to find the WSGI-Applications under the name `application` in the specified module, but you can configure that with the WSGICallableObject configuration directive.

Comment: Okay thanks! Do you know what Google appengine expects the function to be called?